# C# Web App - web address to image thumb as button

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hope you can help. I'm looking for a way to generate a thumb from a web link and then programmatically display the image.

Perfect example is Google Chrome and the home page with the images.

I'm happy to show you the code that gets the web link from my sql data.

Thanks

Comment: Probably not the simplest thing to do. There's 3rd party apps that do it. Did you have something specific you tried and need help with? This question is too generic without more detail.

Comment: @Nikki9696 - Thank you for your response. I have seen some that convert html to image: https://www.nrecosite.com/html_to_image_generator_net.aspx 
Which I think would do the job, but I couldn't get it work. I will try it again and update the question. - Thanks